# Chrome "Jump to Tab" shortcut broken with French Keyboard (OSX)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I've updated my OSX to Mojave yesterday, and Chrome's jump to tab function stopped working. As I have a french keyboard, my default numbers are *& é " ' ( § è ! ç à*, and when hitting shift, *1234567890*.

When I use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> it works, but first, a two finger shortcut is better, and second, <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3-5</kbd> is already taken for screenshots.

Before my OS Upgrade, it all worked smoothly... Chrome doesn't seem to be friend with Mojave as I find it very slow as well...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have the same issue with my keyboard in the Belgian layout. It used to work with cmd + number on Mojave, but I think the Chrome 70 update broke it. Now it's cmd + shift + number.

Comment: And then if you want to go to the third tab, you take a screenshot :)

Comment: I have this issue in High Sierra. Related to Chrome.

Comment: Issue seems to have been fixed in Version 73.0.3683.86!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's a bug in the new release, check out [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=900199).

Comment: precisely that! indeed worked with Chrome 69, hence the suggestion to back version and stop auto update. Thanks for the heads up, will keep an eye!

Comment: Looks like it is fixed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=898638

Comment: Updated to Version 70.0.3538.102 - no change...

Comment: It's now fixed in Version 73.0.3683.86

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to have been fixed in Version 73.0.3683.86!

Comment: I think it's ok, as he answered his own question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually know a way round this, but the "problem" is that with a French keyboard you need to press Shift to get the numbers at all times.
All [most?] other languages don't work this way.

It might be worth experimenting with the other types of French keyboard input - there are a few - & see if one of those will do a better job for you.

[image]

Comment: Well yes, but for some reason, before the update, CMD+é worked as CMD+2 in chrome... now it doesn't anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable with JavaScript programming, you could use the extensions
[Violentmonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/violentmonkey/jinjaccalgkegednnccohejagnlnfdag)
together with
[VM.registerShortcut](https://github.com/violentmonkey/vm-shortcut).

*Violentmonkey* can inject into the displayed page a JavaScript userscript.
*VM.registerShortcut* can intercept entered shortcuts and translate them
to calls of JavaScript functions.

Using both of them enables the mapping of any shortcut to a JavaScript function
call.
For implementing Chrome's "Jump to Tab",
you would be using the
[chrome.tabs API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)
to interact with the browser's tab system where you may do anything
that you like.

For example, to change the current tab you would do :

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { highlighted: true });
```

Lots of additional information about the subject can be found on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks like we'll have to wait a few more weeks:](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=898638#c20)

> There's a patch in review at https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/1372349 , once that is in the fix should in in Canary on the next day. It'll likely be on stable in chrome 73.

For now, I'm using [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) to reassign the 10 missing keyboard shortcuts in Chrome only:

[image]

Comment: So, hopefully, this will be fixed before you need to pay for that software?  :-)

Comment: Fix will be shipped in Chrome 73, currently we're at 71. But I highly recommend paying for it though, it's very useful! ;)

Comment: I'm now using Brave 62 (based on Chromium 73) and it's working again.